# initialize dependency object dynamiclly in dependency injection?

Tags: spring-mvc, dependency-injection

To initialize dependency object we put an entry of bean in '/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml' as:

```
<bean id="carManager" class="springmvc.service.CarManager">
   <property name="carList">
     <list>
       <ref bean="car1"/>
       <ref bean="car2"/>
    </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

for reference bean "car1" and car2" we have entry is:

```
<bean id="car1" class="springmvc.model.Car">
    <property name="id" value="1"/>
    <property name="brand" ref="brand1"/>
    <property name="model" value="SL 500"/>
    <property name="price" value="40000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="car2" class="springmvc.model.Car">
    <property name="id" value="2"/>
    <property name="brand" ref="brand2"/>
    <property name="model" value="607"/>
    <property name="price" value="35000"/>
</bean>
```

so my question is can we prepare "car1" and "car2" bean dynamically. for example in "car1" bean i want car list whoes value is above 40000 so for that i have to take data from DB so how can i call my service or DB query to prepare such bean is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement BeanDefinitionParser and override appropriate method in it.

and use

BeanDefinitionBuilder messageProcessorBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(MessagingPostProcessor.class);
messageProcessorBuilder.addConstructorArgValue(StringUtils.split(packageNames, ","));
registry.registerBeanDefinition(MessagingPostProcessor.class.getName(), messageProcessorBuilder.getBeanDefinition());